# Help me fix shading issue here

Tags: modeling, mesh

Help me fix shading issue here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the *Subdivision Surface* modifier of your boolean cutting object, simplify it (with the *Checker Deselect* you can easily remove the edges and keep only 1 out of 4):

[image]

Select your main object, hide the *Subdivision Surface* modifier for the moment, apply the *Boolean* modifier, rework the topology:

[image]

Bevel the edge to make it sharp:

[image]

With the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I am flabbergasted how you could decipher the way out of this. Much appreciated. BTW, do you have a Youtube channel ? Where you teach how to make stuff?

Comment: yes I have the Blender Moonboots channel but it's in french  ;)

Comment: I subscribed. Hoping to learn even though it's in French! :)

Comment: thanks, don't trust the subtitles though  ;)

Comment: Haha. OK. I'll trust my eyes only!

Comment: I watched one of your video. "Small exercise 7" and I must say you should definitely make  videos in English. It will help so many. Redirect people who need help from here to your YouTube channel. -- >

Comment: it's already exhausting to do it in french, but maybe I'll translate the most popular, good idea, thanks  ;)